# How to return more than two values from service to controller in node js

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a controller/ user.js file to get data using a function from service/user.js
From getUsers function in service I can't return more than 1 value. for example I want to return  `return{User,pages}`. But, i getting error while return like `return{User,pages}`
 The below is thw error i getting while using  `return{User,pages}`

> userService.getUsers(...).then is not a function

**controller/user.js**

```
function getUsers(req, res){
    userService.getUsers({
         page_no:req.body.page_no,
         previous:req.body.previous
    }  
    )
    .then(data => res.send(data));
};
```

**service/user.js**

```
const getUsers = function (data) { 
    let limit = 10;   // number of records per page
    let offset = 0;
    let page = data.page_no;      // page number
     data = Users.findAll({where: {
        DeletedAt: {
          $eq: null
        }
    }})
    const pages = Math.ceil(data.count / limit);
        offset = limit * (page - 1);
    const User =  Users.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'role_id','login','is_active'],
        limit: limit,
        order: [
                ['createdAt', 'DESC']
            ],
        offset: offset,
        $sort: { id: 1 },
        where: {
            DeletedAt: {
              $eq: null
            }
        }
    })
    return User
    };
```

Comment: can you show me the error ?

Comment: @Pushpendra Kumar  thanks for your response. but i solved the issue with the help of 1556089774 's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using some ORM which returns a `Promise`.

When you return just `User`, the type of `User` is (probably, as you do not get error) a `Promise` so the function will return a promise and you can call `.then` method.

However when you return `{ User, pages }`, you're not returning a promise but an `Object` and objects don't have `then` method, which is why you're getting the error.

When you return the object `{ User, pages }`, you can change your code to extract the promise and call then method on it:

```
function getUsers(req, res){
  const { User, pages } = userService.getUsers({
    page_no:req.body.page_no,
    previous:req.body.previous
  })
  // Call the then User which is a Promise
  User.then(data => res.send(data))
};
```

Comment: still i can't get the pages value

Comment: function getUsers(req, res){
  const { User, pages } = userService.getUsers({
    page_no:req.body.page_no,
    previous:req.body.previous
 })
 console.log(pages);
  // Call the then User which is a Promise
  User.then(data => res.send(data))
};

Comment: it returns undefined

Comment: How did you return?